# Why is the code ignoring one of the IF requirements?

Tags: java

I'm sure it's obvious but can't figure out what I'm missing. Code is:

```
} else if (flag != null && date != null &&
!date.equals("") && (disability != null || flagEnd == null)) 

//do stuff

}
```

I've double checked the variables. flag is not null, date IS null, disability is null and flagEng is null. The code shouldn't be stepping into this because the date is null, and yet it is. Do I have this written incorrectly?

Note: date is a string. flagEnd is a java.util.Date. Thanks!

Edit: Here is the code that creates the date variable.

```
String date = (rs.getString("date") != null && rs.getString("date").length() > 0 ? rs.getString("date") : "NULL");
```

Instead of date != null, should I maybe instead have this?

```
!date.equals("NULL")
```

Comment: What you're describing doesn't sound possible. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Trying walking through this with a debugger and insert a breakpoint on the `else if` line. Once the code stops there you can inspect each variable to see what the values of each are.
Edit: Random thought... What if date is the string "null" rather than a null reference?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. Here are the variables themselves:
flag DefaultElement  (id=86), date "NULL" (id=66), disability null, flagEnd null. EDIT: You might be onto something there, the string is coming from a database read. Let me try it as if null is a value instead of a null reference.

Comment: Sounds like date == "NULL" and != null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string was actually storing the word "NULL", as opposed to being an empty string. Once I changed the code to !date.equals("NULL"), it skipped the ELSE IF statement like it should have.